# Set WriteFixedPosHTML in all pages

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I need to add text on ALL created pages. How to do this?

```
$mpdf->WriteFixedPosHTML('<table border="0"><tr><th text-rotate="90" style="font-family: Arial;font-weight: normal;">www.siteeee.com</th></tr></table>', 10, 190, 3, 0, 'visible');
```

This code above is only on the first page. How do I pin to all pages?

Comment: Header and/or footer? https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html Or a watermark https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/watermarks.html

Comment: @Finwe I already use header and footer, for their respective functionalities. This new markup needs to be positioned vertically on each page. This code above is only on the first page, I need it on all of them.